# a function-definition is not allowed here: void encryption(ifstream encrypt_file, ofstream keys_out, ofstream cipher_out) {

Tags: c++

I believe the error is coming from somewhere between the void function declaration and definition.

In class, we've been reading in the input values for file names in the void functions, but for this assignment, they're to be read in the main class.

I want to be able to read in the values in the main class, then I will later code in an encryption and decryption method in my encryption() and decryption() functions. Is there any advice on how to do that considering the code is opened in the main class and not the void functions?

> Errors:
>
> In function ‘int main()’: 119:79: error: a function-definition
>   is not allowed here before ‘{’ token  void decryption(ifstream
>   decrypt_in, ofstream keys_in, ofstream plaintxt_out) {
>                                                                                  ^ 125:80: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’
>   token  void encryption(ifstream encrypt_file, ofstream keys_out,
>   ofstream cipher_out) {
>                                                                                   ^ 125:80: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’
>   token

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>


using namespace std;

void decryption(ifstream& decrypt_in, ifstream& keys_in, ofstream& 
plaintxt_out);
void encryption(ifstream& encrypt_in, ofstream& keys_out, ofstream& 
cipher_out);
int main() {


    enum encrypt_and_decrypt { ENCRYPT = 'E', DECRYPT = 'D'};

    char enc_or_dec; 

    ifstream decrypt_in;
    ifstream encrypt_in;
    ifstream keys_in;

    ofstream plaintxt_out;
    ofstream keys_out;
    ofstream cipher_out;


    cout << "Enter E or D: ";
    cin >> enc_or_dec;

    if (enc_or_dec == 'e') {
        enc_or_dec = ENCRYPT;
    }
    if (enc_or_dec == 'd') {
        enc_or_dec = DECRYPT;
    }



    while (enc_or_dec != ENCRYPT && enc_or_dec != DECRYPT) {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Please try again. \nWould you like to ENCRYPT or DECRYPT the file? ";
        cin >> enc_or_dec;

    }

    switch (enc_or_dec) {

    default:
        cout << "Error";

        break; 

    case DECRYPT:


        char decrypt_file[33];
        char plaintext_file[33];
        char keys_file[33];
        cout << "Enter the name of your input file you want to decrypt: \n";
        cin >> decrypt_file;
        cout << "Enter the name of the output file to write the plaintext: \n";
        cin >> plaintext_file;
        cout << "Enter the file name that contains your encryption keys: \n";
        cin >> keys_file;

        decrypt_in.open(decrypt_file);
        if (decrypt_in.fail()) {
            cout << "Input file opening for decryption failed.";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        keys_in.open(keys_file);
        if (keys_in.fail()) {
            cout << "Input file opening for encryption keys failed.";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        plaintxt_out.open(plaintext_file); //connect to the output file and test
        if (plaintxt_out.fail()) {
            cout << "Output file opening for plaintext failed. \n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit if cannot open
        }

        decryption(decrypt_in, keys_in, plaintxt_out);

        break;

    case ENCRYPT:


            char encrypt_file[33];
        char ciphertext_file[33];
        char keys_file[33];
        cout << "Enter the name of your input file you want to encrypt: \n";
        cin >> encrypt_file;
        cout << "Enter the name of the output file to write the ciphertext: \n";
        cin >> ciphertext_file;
        cout << "Enter the file name that will contain your encryption keys: \n";
        cin >> keys_file;

        encrypt_in.open(encrypt_file);
        if (encrypt_in.fail()) {
            cout << "Input file opening for encryption failed.";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        keys_out.open(keys_file);
        if (keys_out.fail()) {
            cout << "Output file opening for encryption keys failed.";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        cipher_out.open(ciphertext_file); //connect to the output file and test
        if (cipher_out.fail()) {
            cout << "Output file opening for ciphertext failed. \n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit if cannot open
        }
        encryption(encrypt_in, keys_out, cipher_out); 
        break;

}

void decryption(ifstream& decrypt_in, ofstream& keys_in, ofstream& plaintxt_out) {
    decrypt_in.close();
    keys_in.close();
    plaintxt_out.close();
}

void encryption(ifstream& encrypt_file, ofstream& keys_out, ofstream& cipher_out) {
    encrypt_file.close();
    keys_out.close();
    cipher_out.close();
}

}
```

return 0;

Comment: Not sure how the top of my code lost its indention; sorry about that.

Comment: Many lines of code .... what line is the error reported to be on and what's the exact message?

Comment: @RichardCritten , I edited and included the error messages w/the correct line numbers where errors occur. Thank you for that!

Comment: Voted to close as a typo. Missed '}' resulting in functions being defined inside `main`, which is, as the error specifies, not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function definitions are actually inside the scope of main(), which is not allowed.  Try moving that dangling "}" at the end of the file up a few lines.

Comment: So I went ahead and did that, and now I have a new error message.

Comment: (.text+0x508): undefined reference to `encryption(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Gbrandonconner That would be a new question.,

Comment: I figured it out! I had accidentally used a different name in my function definition compared to the declaration, and also had two ofstream& and 1 ifstream& in decryption's decleration, but 1 ofstream& and 2 ifstream& in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Your braces aren't matched how you think they are. The error message is telling you that you can't define a function where it's being defined - which is actually within `main()`. Quoting your code below:

```
int main() {
    ...
    switch(enc_or_dec) {
    ...
} // (1) <-- closing switch() statement

void decryption(ifstream& decrypt_in, ofstream& keys_in, ofstream& plaintxt_out) {
    decrypt_in.close();
    keys_in.close();
    plaintxt_out.close();
}

void encryption(ifstream& encrypt_file, ofstream& keys_out, ofstream& cipher_out) {
    encrypt_file.close();
    keys_out.close();
    cipher_out.close();
}

} // (2) <-- closing main()
```

You'll notice that what you (probably) think is the brace closing `main()` is actually closing `switch(enc_or_dec)`. This is why you have an otherwise-random brace at the end of the file. Removing the brace at `(2)` and adding another at `(1)` should fix the issue, by taking your definitions of `encryption` and `decryption` outside of `main`.

Comment: here's what i got when doing that ------------------ > "(.text+0x508): undefined reference to `encryption(std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

Comment: I copied and tried your code. I didn't get that error, but I got two different compiler errors: First, from redefinition of `keys_file`. You can't declare the same variable in two different `case` statements - best to put the contents of `DECRYPT` and `ENCRYPT` in their own blocks (e.g. `case DECRYPT: { ... break; }`). Second, more similar to your current error - where the issue was that the declaration of `decryption` (above main) has the second argument as type `ifstream`, while the definition uses `ofstream`, presumably a typo. Fix those and it might work.

Comment: it worked! Just before you sent this in, I went thru and figured it out based on another stackoverflow post. Thank you so much for your help.